# jQuery get count of N elements in tinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to get a count of the number of <!--nextpage--> comment tags inside the tinyMCE editor (WordPress).

What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    //find the count of nextpage elements
    var n = jQuery("#content").find("<!--nextpage-->").length;
    alert(n);
});
```

Comment: Comments are not part of the DOM and jQuery wont find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are not traversable DOM nodes like inputs, divs etc. and jQuery wont find them.

Instead you can try doing a string search for the particular comment inside the element's `innerHTML`.

```
var count = $('#foo').html().split("<!--nextpage-->").length - 1;
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/46wYS/

---

Updated demo using a lenient regex for splitting: http://jsfiddle.net/46wYS/1/

```
var count = $('#foo').html().split(/<!--\s*boo\s* -->/i).length - 1;
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, but I'm getting 0 from alert(count) even though there are several matches in the html source.

Comment: Ensure that the comment string you search for is **exactly** the same as in your HTML. I mean spaces in between, case etc. OR use a more forgiving regex variant.

Comment: Actually, works a charm. Just had to change the split text to &lt;!--nextpage--&gt;

Comment: Cool. To be safer, use a lenient regex for case and space insensitivity as in the updated demo.